# reduce for loop time in dataframe operation

Tags: python, dataframe

To see the sample response check this on browser https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-ETH&tickInterval=thirtyMin. I have 275 values market list, and 330 time interval in time_series list. GetTicks api have 1000s of list of dict. I am only interested in those record where interval in time_series matches with 'T' value in GetTicks api. if time_series doesnt not matches with 'T' value in GetTicks api then I am setting respective values of 'BV'/'L' in master df as 0. Each loop is taking 3 second to execute, making around 20-25minute of execution time. is there a better pythonic way to construct this master df in less time ? Appreciate your help/suggestion.

my code --->

```
for (mkt, market_pair) in enumerate(market_list):
    getTicks = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=" + str(
        market_pair) + "&tickInterval=thirtyMin")
    getTicks_result = (getTicks.json())["result"]
    print(mkt + 1, '/', len_market_list, market_pair, "API called", datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    first_df = pd.DataFrame(getTicks_result)
    first_df.set_index('T', inplace=True)

    for tk, interval in enumerate(time_series):
        if interval in first_df.index:
            master_bv_df.loc[market_pair, interval] = first_df.loc[interval,'BV']
            bv_sh.cell(row=mkt + 2, column=tk + 3).value = first_df.loc[interval,'BV']
            master_lp_df.loc[market_pair, interval] = first_df.loc[interval,'L']
            lp_sh.cell(row=mkt + 2, column=tk + 3).value = first_df.loc[interval,'L']
        else:
            master_bv_df.loc[market_pair, interval] = master_lp_df.loc[market_pair, interval]=0
            bv_sh.cell(row=mkt + 2, column=tk + 3).value = lp_sh.cell(row=mkt + 2, column=tk + 3).value=0
```